# How to make Scatter Graph appear clearer

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to python and i was wondering if i could make my scatter graph appear clearer than it is currently:
[image]

My code is :

```
plot.scatter(data[Var 1],data[Var 2])
plot.shows()
```

I believe the data I am using might also be an issue as there is almost a million records. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: you can use transparency to show the distribution of your data in a less cluttered way. But with a million datapoints, you might want to think about randomly sampling and then plotting a subset of, say, 2000 datapoints.

Comment: It depends on what you are doing, but you may want a 2-d histogram.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could decrease the size of the markers to make the plot a little clearer.

pyplot.scatter() has the parameter s to adjust the size:

> s: float or array-like, shape (n, ), optional: The marker size in points**2

But with a million records, your dataset might just be too large to get a clear graph. If the data allows, it might help to only plot a random subset